# What is the easiest/simplest browser game engine?

Tags: java, javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I make mobile games, but I would like to make some simple browser based clients for my social games so that we can debug more easily. What is the the easiest engine to do this with?

I have looked at some HTML5 engines and GWT, but I would like an opinion from the community. I am looking for an engine that is capable of basic animations (nothing too fancy, just transitioning images from one location to another) and the capacity to do basic networking (sockets + HTTP calls).

The main criterion I am looking for is ease of use with the basic functionality. If there is something similar to gosu for the web, that would be ideal. http://www.libgosu.org/

I use Ruby for my server backend if that helps.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330782/ideas-for-a-simple-game and its related questions.

Comment: I use HTML5 canvas and HTML5 WebSockets. The canvas doesn't include an animation library by default but it's extremely flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a game engine. You've got the DOM to draw too.

You can use [Emile](https://github.com/madrobby/emile) for animations.

And use [`socket-io`](http://socket.io/) for your networking. You may have some trouble getting it to talk to RoR though. You may have to find an alternative (or use node.js!)

Apparently [Socky](https://github.com/socky/socky-server-ruby) is good for networking with RoR.

Comment: I'm actually using EventMachine to create the actual game. I'll look at using straight DOM I guess.

Comment: @slick28 depends what you want, SVG (rapheal) or canvas (crafty) are good too.